# In nativescript-angular how to check whether <ng-content> is empty?

Tags: angular2-nativescript

in my nativescript-angular project I have a component like this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label *ngIf="ngContentIsEmpty"> ng-content is empty </Label>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</StackLayout>
```

Now, I would like to display some content if `<ng-content>` for this component is empty.Is there an easy way to do this?

I've tried this but not work in nativescript:

```
<StackLayout #wrapper>
    <Label *ngIf="wrapper.childNodes.length == 0"> ng-content is empty </Label>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to this for check **ng-content** is empty.

Add In Html File:-

```
<StackLayout *ngIf="ngContentIsEmpty">Content</StackLayout>
<StackLayout #wrapper>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</StackLayout>
```

In TypeScript File:-

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChild('wrapper') wrapper:ElementRef;
  public ngContentIsEmpty = false;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
   this.ngContentIsEmpty= this.wrapper.childNodes.length > 0;
  }

}
```